# "Encryption Failed" on my Samsung Note 2 & it asks me to reset device. Is there a way to back up my data

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have *Samsung Galaxy Note 2* from AT&T. At the reboot it displays "Encryption failed", and would ask me to reset device.

I cannot access my phone. I have very important data on this phone. I want to save my data, I am not bothered about the device, all I want is to save my data and after that even if the phone doesnt work I will get a new phone but I want my data as in pictures and contacts. Is there any way to recover them?