# Samsung Galaxy encryption failed

Tags: factory-reset, encryption

I updated my GT-19100 Phone to 4.1.2 Jelly Bean from the previous version. For this venture it was necessary to decrypt my phone first. After the update I started again an encryption. The process failed (i just left the encryption continue by leaving the phone alone) and the phone showed me this message:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J37aZaq.png]

After reseting the device I can't access any previous data on the phone, nor can I save something on the phone. The phone recommends to format the device.

Is there a way to get my old data back? How could I avoid such a problem next time?
Any advice appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Similar to this question: ["Encryption Failed" on my Samsung Note 2 & it asks me to reset device. Is there a way to back up my data](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46791/encryption-failed-on-my-samsung-note-2-it-asks-me-to-reset-device-is-there) But still not answered.

Comment: If you clicked "Reset device", then it erased all your data as it claimed, and no, you can't get it back.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Probably I should do next time a backup.