# Cyanogenmod: Encryption unsuccessful

Tags: cyanogenmod, factory-reset, encryption

I encrypted my phone. That worked fine. Then I installed another version of Cyanogenmod. This cannot decrypt the data (which is OK: There is no important data on the phone). It tells me to perform a factory reset, but even after the factory reset the phone is stuck at the "Encryption unsuccessful".

The error I get is the same as on:
[Samsung Galaxy encryption failed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55014/samsung-galaxy-encryption-failed)

How do I convince Cyanogenmod that all encrypted data is deleted?

I have tried:

- Factory reset
- Installing the version of Cyanogenmod that encrypted the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory reset failed to **format** `/data` (and thus most likely left the old encryption in place).

Having formatted `/data` manually, the factory reset finally could complete successfully, and the new version of Cyanogenmod showed up.

Comment: @Downvoters: This perfectly makes sense to me, so I re-phrased it to make it easier to grasp: it could well be that CM did not know the "old" encryption key, and thus was unable to access the (existing) file system. Formatting the partition created a "virgin" file system without encryption, and thus made it accessible again (to my understanding).

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter recovery mode, (mine is TWRP 2.8.1), than from recovery change data system type to etx4.

Answer (score -1):

Format `sdcard0` *(internal storage)* to `ext3` file-system format  and it is going to be OK!