# Bricked Note GT-8013, unable to boot from TWRP recovery (flashes logo for 1-2 secs), nor on normal mode, installed TWRP via both IMG and TAR

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, heimdall

I'm running a Samsung Note GT-N8013. One day, my tablet fails to boot, saying that encryption had been unsuccessful; according to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/65301/224428), `/data` has failed to format. I can't reset the device, pressing the reset button on the screen does nothing. I also can't boot into TWRP recovery mode, it just flashes the logo screen for 1-2 seconds and switches back to the Samsung Note logo screen. I've tried to reinstall TWRP into the recovery partition using both `twrp-2.8.7.0-gt-n8013.img` and `twrp-2.8.6.0-gt-n8013.tar` with Heimdall.

Comment: Try flashing a full factory firmware. This does smell like a fried NAND chip so I doubt that would be any success.

Comment: @AndyYan I have the firmware downloaded as a ZIP archive. Where should I flash it to?

Comment: You see a `.tar` or `.tar.md5` (or multiple) inside it? Use Odin/Heimdall to flash. Plenty of instructions around the web.

Comment: Yes, I've extracted the archive. The contents of the firmware are a bit different than those shown in guides, I have: `boot.img*    PM_sharkl_arm7.bin*  sboot.bin*   SPRDGDSP.img*    system.img*
cache.img*   recovery.img*        spl.img*     SPRDLTEDSP.img*
hidden.img*  sboot2.bin*          SPRDCP.img*  SPRDWDSP.img*`. Apparently, I'm missing critical files like `zImage` and a PIT file.

Comment: Sounds looks like the file is actually a `.tar` or `.tar.md5` but renamed to `.zip`. Rename it back and flash. `zImage` is part of the kernel (`boot.img`); PIT is not always needed.

Comment: How do you mean? I can't flash a TAR archive, right? Every tutorial I've found requires the individual files to be flashed to their corresponding partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71073/discussion-between-pradana-aumars-and-andy-yan).

Comment: I've flashed the correct firmware into the system, now it just gets stuck on the Android logo during boot.

Comment: Curiously though, when it returns the "Encryption unsuccessful" window, I still have control over the sound and I can take a screenshot. It also has the "back" button in the bottom bar.