# Samsung GT-N8013 tablet listed as a GT-I9100 phone in lsusb on Linux

Tags: samsung, usb, linux, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have a Samsung GT-N8013 tablet in Download mode, using the stock recovery since TWRP coulnd't work (go [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188833/224428) for more information), connected to a Linux machine. `adb` cannot classify my tablet as a device on Linux, so I had to follow [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/224428). When I found its ID, I found that it had a different name entirely:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
```

How is this possible?

---

<sub>Update 23-02-2018:</sub>

I plugged in the tablet again and booted it normally. It ran into the "encryption unsuccessful" error, however I ran `lsusb` and it yielded

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e8:685c Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9250 Phone [Galaxy Nexus] (Mass storage mode)
```

What's going on to the tablet?

---

I do also want to point out that it has LineageOS installed before I flashed the stock ROM and recovery, but it has not been working ever since.

Comment: what is listed when you type `adb devices`?

Comment: Nothing, `adb` can't detect it.

Comment: Did you enabled `USB Debugging` before you tried with `adb devices`?

Comment: I'm not certain I did. The problem is, the tablet is bricked, so I can't really access it at all. I've tried to flash it with the stock ROM and recovery but nothing has changed.